# How to safely capture someone when you have super-strength

Tags: super-powers, criminal-underworld, safety

In the question [How to safely knock someone out](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101134/how-to-safely-knock-someone-out), it was explained to me that there isn't such a way.

In which case, for a prospective superhero with super-strength and super-durability, what would be the safest way to capture random thugs off the street for the police to collect? Assume that the thugs pose negligible threat to the superhero.

EDIT: When I said safely, I meant safely for the thug. The hero doesn't want to risk Grievous Bodily Harm charges later.

Comment: How is this about building a fictional world? This seems like a question about how to resolve a scenario in the world you've created.

Comment: @sphennings - It would affect the ethics of the world if it wasn't possible to arrest people if only super strength as weapon. Applicable to a scenario of unarmed robots as police. No web goo shooter, stunner, gas, etc, just strength (and "durability"; man of steel bullet-proof?), makes for an interesting scenario in that it doesn't seek a technological answer to question, implying a world where weaponry isn't the answer to everything. Just imagining such a world is interesting and this issue would reflect widespread consequences and a unique-ish history.

Comment: The question isn't about the ethics of the world. The question is how to capture someone when you have super strength. The world is built. Super strength exists. The OP is asking how a super hero uses their powers. Questions asking what should a character do in this situation are off topic.

Comment: You're right and answers clearly show it's down to immobilization. I was reading more into the question. Perhaps OP can make it more interesting?

Comment: @sphennings What sort of detail could I add to make this question more appropriate? I could add more background information, but that wouldn't change the actual question. Alternatively, which stackexchange site should this question go on?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of an exchange that this question would be a good fit for. I also don't think that adding more detail will resolve the structural issue of asking about the actions of an individual in your world.

Answer (score 11):

If a lion, a tiger or an alligator, though being able of crunching an animal with a bite of their jaw, can gently hold and carry their cubs using the very same jaws, I can imagine that also a superhero, though being super strong, is able of modulating the strength he exercises.

Using this modulation he can restrain the tug and, once restrained, use conventional immobilizers like handcuff or ropes to secure that the felon won't escape justice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116038/discussion-on-answer-by-l-dutch-reinstate-monica-how-to-safely-capture-someone).

Answer (score 10):

Handcuffs and gentle handling is possible, of course, but what about using mere *intimidation*?

From your questions it seems that we're mostly dealing with common thugs, not some insane revenge-fueled supervillain. Common thugs are very much human.

If your superhero is able to show a display of overwhelming raw power, such as shrugging off any attack the thugs do or bend/crush nearby solid objects, then perhaps the thug would realize that giving up is the best thing they can do in the situation. Having increased speed may help too, to make the idea of escaping all but impossible. "Just give up and nobody needs to get hurt" and all that.

Only once all of that fails would you resort to physical capture, preferably as effortlessly as possible (Swiftly handcuffing them, easily lifting them off the ground as if they're small children, etc) so it would further cement the image of overwhelming power once the story spreads all over media.

In fact, once you've done this often enough, your reputation will probably precede you and your mere presence would be enough to intimidate nearby thugs to turn themselves in.

Comment: So much this. The fact that rando thugs still try to fight _Superman_ is extremely unrealistic. If you are Random Mugger #2857 and all of a sudden the guy in bright blue tights who you have _seen take tank rounds to the face on live TV_ and has _gotten in fights that leveled skyscrapers_ lands in front of you... Yeah, you might take a swing at him or open fire in panic...but when that doesn't work and he just tells you to surrender while folding your getaway car in half...you're probably going to do so. And need new pants.

Comment: @guildsbounty, remember:  after shooting at Superman, you need to throw the gun at him.  The empty gun is, apparently, more effective than the high speed bullets since the George Reeves Superman would actually duck the gun.

Answer (score 9):

**Big bag.**

[image: raccoon going into bag]
from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-frp2gYp2I

"Getting them in the sack is the hard part".

Your super has a roll of big fabric bags.  He has them made special.  They are tough.  He opens one up and then pulls it over the criminal.  Then he closes up the top.

It is easy for one super to carry a lot of criminals in their bags.   If you have a knife you might cut your way out.  These bags have steel threads (like those in steel belted tires) woven in which makes the cutting very slow.  If you have a gun you could shoot through the bag.  That would let individuals express their frustration at being in the bag but will not otherwise help much.  Other criminals in other nearby bags will probably yell at the shooter to stop.

A fabric bag will not cause a criminal to suffocate.   The criminal could still use a phone from within the bag.  Bags are washable and reusable which helps the earth.

When you want to ask a criminal something you could let him poke his head out of the bag.  If he is helpful you could let him leave it out.  I do not think you should do that with a raccoon.

Comment: This! This is the best answer. Made me giggle out loud :D

Comment: Instead of steel try something like gold - it’s durable and conductive, so not only can’t he cut his way out but he also can’t make a phone call.

Comment: @DonielF:  Faraday cage sack - nice.   I might try to work out one of the gold wires to steal during my time in the sack.

Comment: @Will I don’t know enough on the subject to determine how valuable it would be, but I suppose trying to saw your way through that will keep you busy enough until the cops arrive.

Comment: +1 for "Bags are washable and reusable which helps the earth."

Answer (score 5):

Just do what the police do, and put the bad guys in handcuffs. They use those for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

If super strength is the problem, you need to do something that involves as little body contact as possible. The best case scenario involves no contact at all.

So the best possibility with current technology is tasing the bad guys, just like the police do sometimes. The worst thing that can happen is someone being hit in the eye or neck.

Failing that, tranquilizer guns. Same risks as tasers, though not as safe.

If the hero is not willing to use handheld weapons, and supposing their lungs are as strong as their arms, he or she could just shout out so loud that the thugs would be stunned. You may end up giving innocent people some level of deafness, but then again you can't make an omelet without popping some eardrums.

Comment: [Tasers aren't so safe.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser_safety_issues). If you hit someone who isn't healthy...or has even overly exerted themselves recently...it is entirely possible to stop their heart with a taser. And that's just one example...

Answer (score 1):

By the clothes; if they don't have hem, by the hair.

Otherwise I think of it as catching a bird, you need to fold it in a natural way as fast as possible to immobilize it.

For a human the best way might be to hold it by the ankles (both if possible) and raise it in the air, slowly, guiding it so it keeps straight.

If it falls down, you would shake it so to be suspended in the air overpowered (like in a roller coaster), then as it falls, catch it by holding the abdomen.

If it still fights, then fold it (in two) against your body.